# Is there any advantage to declaring a class static in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

In C#, you can declare a class as static, which requires all members to also be static. Is there any advantage (e.g. performance) to be gained by doing so? Or is it only a matter of making sure you don't accidentally declare instance members in your class?

Comment: Just a small comment/anecdote: That "accidentially declare instance members" was the reason static classes got introduced in C# 2.0. Originally it didn't support it and with .net Framework 1.1 the `Environment` class had an Instance Property, but no public ctor, making that property inaccessible except through reflection which required full trust.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Or is it only a matter of making sure you don't accidentally declare instance members in your class?

It's that, but it's more than that:

- It prevents instantiation by not having an instance constructor at all (whereas *all* other classes have a constructor - either one you declare or an implicit parameterless one)
- It expresses your *intention* clearly
- Nothing can derive from your class (it's both sealed and abstract)
- Nothing can declare a field of your class type
- Nothing can use your type as a generic type argument

Basically it tells the compiler and other developers "This is never meant to be instantiated - so if it looks like you're trying to use an instance, you're doing it wrong."

I doubt that there are any *performance* benefits, but all the above are enough for me :)

Oh, and you can only declare extension methods in static classes too...

Comment: The first point might be a bit misleading. You forgot static constructors :)

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou: Fixed, although in my experience "constructor" with no modifier is pretty much *always* used to implicitly mean "instance constructor".

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are close to answer, sharing the link which might answer your question.
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103914/why-and-when-should-i-make-a-class-static-what-is-the-purpose-of-static-key